# Grab source from Google Code using wget or curl?

Tags: python, wget, curl, mercurial, google-code

Is it possible to grab the source-code from a Google Code repository (hg) using wget or curl?

Else using Python?

Thanks for all suggestions

FYI: I'm on a shared WebFaction host, so can't install hg

Comment: Google Code provides HTTP interfaces to the repositories if I'm not mistaken. Example: http://mercurialeclipse.eclipselabs.org.codespot.com/hg/

Comment: So what, a recursive wget call using awk?

Comment: `wget --mirror` or something similar, should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use Google's HTTP interface to their repositories.

The easiest way would be to grab a *raw file link*:
[image]

And then dissect the URL.

You can then download the files with `curl`, or *mirror* the whole repository (or, at least the current revision) with `wget`. For example

```
wget --mirror https://typo3scripts.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/
```